# Best practices using python mock for testing functions within sub modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

So,
consider I have a simple library that I am trying to write unit-tests for. This library talks to a database and then uses that data to call an SOAP API. I have three modules, and a testfile for each module.

dir structure:

```
./mypkg
    ../__init__.py
    ../main.py
    ../db.py
    ../api.py

./tests
    ../test_main
    ../test_db
    ../test_api
```

Code:

```
#db.py
import mysqlclient
class Db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._client = mysqlclient.Client()

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._client.some_query()


#api.py
import soapclient
class Api(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._client = soapclient.Client()

    @property
    def call(self):
        return self._client.some_external_call()


#main.py
from db import Db
from api import Api

class MyLib(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Db()
        self.api = Api()

    def caller(self):
        return self.api.call(self.db.data)
```

Unit-Tests:

```
#test_db.py
import mock
from mypkg.db import Db

@mock.patch('mypkg.db.mysqlclient')
def test_db(mysqlclient_mock):
    mysqlclient_mock.Client.return_value.some_query = {'data':'data'}
    db = Db()
    assert db.data == {'data':'data'}


#test_api.py
import mock
from mypkg.api import Api

@mock.patch('mypkg.db.soapclient')
def test_db(soap_mock):
    soap_mock.Client.return_value.some_external_call = 'foo'
    api = Api()
    assert api.call == 'foo'
```

In the above example, `mypkg.main.MyLib` calls `mypkg.db.Db()` (uses third-party `mysqlclient`) and then `mypkg.api.Api()` (uses third-party `soapclient`)

I am using `mock.patch` to patch the third-party libraries to mock my db and api calls in `test_db` and `test_api` separately.

Now my question is, is it recommended to patch these external calls again in `test_main` OR simply patch `db.Db` and `api.Api`? (this example is pretty simple, but in larger libraries, the code becomes cumbersome when patching the external calls again or even using test helper functions that patch internal libraries).

Option1: patch external libraries in `main` again

```
#test_main.py
import mock
from mypkg.main import MyLib

@mock.patch('mypkg.db.mysqlclient')
@mock.patch('mypkg.api.soapclient')
def test_main(soap_mock, mysqlcient_mock):
    ml = MyLib()
    soap_mock.Client.return_value.some_external_call = 'foo'
    assert ml.caller() == 'foo'
```

Option2: patch internal libraries

```
#test_main.py
import mock
from mypkg.main import MyLib

@mock.patch('mypkg.db.Db')
@mock.patch('mypkg.api.Api')
def test_main(api_mock, db_mock):
    ml = MyLib()
    api_mock.return_value = 'foo'
    assert ml.caller() == 'foo'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mock.patch` creates a mock version of something *where it's imported*, not where it lives. This means the string passed to `mock.patch` has to be a path to an imported module in the module under test. Here's what the patch decorators should look like in `test_main.py`:

```
@mock.patch('mypkg.main.Db')
@mock.patch('mypkg.main.Api')
```

Also, the handles you have on your patched modules (`api_mock` and `db_mock`) refer to the *classes*, not instances of those classes. When you write `api_mock.return_value = 'foo'`, you're telling api_mock to return 'foo' when it gets called, not when an instance of it has a method called on it. Here are the objects in main.py and how they relate to `api_mock` and `db_mock` in your test:

```
Api is a class                     : api_mock
Api() is an instance               : api_mock.return_value
Api().call is an instance method   : api_mock.return_value.call
Api().call() is a return value     : api_mock.return_value.call.return_value

Db is a class                      : db_mock
Db() is an instance                : db_mock.return_value
Db().data is an attribute          : db_mock.return_value.data
```

test_main.py should therefore look like this:

```
import mock
from mypkg.main import MyLib

@mock.patch('mypkg.main.Db')
@mock.patch('mypkg.main.Api')
def test_main(api_mock, db_mock):
    ml = MyLib()

    api_mock.return_value.call.return_value = 'foo'
    db_mock.return_value.data = 'some data' # we need this to test that the call to api_mock had the correct arguments.

    assert ml.caller() == 'foo'
    api_mock.return_value.call.assert_called_once_with('some data')
```

The first patch in Option 1 would work great for unit-testing `db.py`, because it gives the db module a mock version of mysqlclient. Similarly, `@mock.patch('mypkg.api.soapclient')` belongs in `test_api.py`.

I can't think of a way Option 2 could help you unit-test anything.

Edited: I was incorrectly referring to classes as modules. db.py and api.py are modules